# how to find duplicates in Big query having nested data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, etl

I have table structure like below and need to find the duplicate records in Google big query

```
|- Main category
|- Field 1
|- Field 2
|- Field 3

+- sub category
    |- Field 1
    |- Field 2
    |- Field 3
    +- sub sub category
        |- Field 1
        |- Field 2
        |- Field 3
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this? Essentially, create a json string from the array, group them and exclude counts=1.

```sql
with test as (

    select * from unnest([
        struct(1 as id, [1,2,3] as subc),
        (2, [3,4,5]),
        (3, [1,2,3])
    ])
)

select 
    to_json_string(subc) as dupl
from test
group by 1
having count(dupl)>1
```